# Get time elapsed from boot til main method call in Java

Tags: java, time

I am currently working on a Java application (company uses both stand-alone and webapps) which already has quite a large source-code. Since I am trying to optimize its boot time, I was wondering if I could check how long the application takes to actually boot up prior to reaching the main method.

And if possible, the more specific times such as 'Maven took 10000ms, Spring took 450000ms'.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: what kind of application is it? web/ standalone?

Comment: We're using both actually (multiple applications). A solution to either would already help me out quite a lot :)